# Is there a word or phrase for someone whose ominous remarks come true?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, idiom-requests

Someone who makes such comments as:

> - "Look at his car tyres! He is inviting an accident."   (and he does suffer an accident minutes later.)
> - "I never have shrimps with pepper. You're likely to have diarrhea. (this is foolish but the listener has shrimps with pepper and also gets the runs the following day.)

I'm not looking for the word "clairvoyant" or any other related to parapsychology. The comments are not wishes, and the fact that they happen is just a coincidence.  You might even tell this person: "Please, don't say anything about me.  Your comments attract bad luck!"

Comment: Rather than saying "you have a terrible mouth" which I would understand to mean that the person has either ugly-looking teeth, or suffers from halitosis, I'd say "Please, don't say anything to me. You only bring bad luck!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Jinx**

> [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jinx) *n*.
>   1. A person or thing that is believed to bring bad luck.
>   2. A condition or period of bad luck that appears to have been caused by a specific person or thing.
>   *tr.v.* jinxed, jinx·ing, jinx·es
>   **To bring bad luck to**.

If a person is *jinxed* (adjective), it means that he or she always has bad luck. If you are experiencing a series of misfortunes, you can say that somebody has **put a jinx on** you.

In the OP's examples the person speaking is "responsible" for causing the unfortunate incidents, hence she/he *is a jinx* (noun).

[Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/jinx) explains it well

> **If your sister gets a flat tire every single time you ride in her car,
>   she may have good reason to accuse you of being *a jinx*, or a bringer
>   of bad luck.**
>
> When your bad luck makes you think there's a jinx on you,
>   you believe that you're cursed. A bad omen — like a black cat — can be
>   called a jinx, or the resulting bad fortune itself might be referred
>   to that way. *Jinx* is also a verb, meaning "to subject to bad luck." In
>   the 17th century the word was *jyng*, which also meant a bird called a
>   "wryneck," used in witchcraft.

Answer (score 10):

The person can be called a *[Cassandra](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Cassandra)*

> (as noun a Cassandra) A prophet of disaster, especially one who is disregarded.

This is based on the character Cassandra from Greek mythology

> A daughter of the Trojan king Priam, who was given the gift of prophecy by Apollo. When she cheated him, however, he turned this into a curse by causing her prophecies, though true, to be disbelieved.

[both from *Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Comment: Here's another source: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheCassandra

Comment: My first thought. Of course, the term is only truly appropriate when the predictions of disaster are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call that person ***bad luck***

> "You're bad luck, you are." <sub><sup>[You're my Henry Allbones - G. B. Hope](http://books.google.com/books?id=spfwwNP5augC&pg=PA225&dq=%22you%27re+bad+luck%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ytAcVNPrMYj8oQTknICoAQ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22you%27re%20bad%20luck%22&f=false)</sup></sub>
>
> "Maybe you're bad luck." <sub><sup>[Hero - E. V. Crowe](http://books.google.com/books?id=24IwgF1gFEAC&pg=PT73&dq=%22you%27re+bad+luck%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ytAcVNPrMYj8oQTknICoAQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22you%27re%20bad%20luck%22&f=false)</sup></sub>
>
> "You're bad luck. I bet you're bad luck to yourself." "He is, kid," Blocker said. <sub><sup>[Yesterday Will Make You Cry - Chester B. Himes](http://books.google.com/books?id=46mhsODubZUC&pg=PA173&dq=%22you%27re+bad+luck%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ytAcVNPrMYj8oQTknICoAQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22you%27re%20bad%20luck%22&f=false)</sup></sub>